# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for with symlinks

Tags: environment-variables, symbolic-link, paths

As per [the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables) - the only way to permanently set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is by adding a conf file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

If I manually run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/nextcloudapp/squashfs-root/usr/lib` then the libraries in that path are accessible and I'm able to run my program.

If I edit `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nextcloudlibs.conf` and add `/home/me/nextcloudapp/squashfs-root/usr/lib/` and then run `sudo ldconfig` I get the following error:

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: /home/me/nextcloudapp/squashfs-root/usr/lib/libnextcloud_csync.so.0 is not a symbolic link`

Is there any way to resolve that error?

Looking at the file listing, it does appear to be a symbolic link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me        23 Mar 31 23:34 libnextcloud_csync.so -> libnextcloud_csync.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me   1202224 Mar 31 23:34 libnextcloud_csync.so.0
```

The libraries are extracted from [an AppImage](https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/releases/download/v3.7.4/Nextcloud-3.7.4-x86_64.AppImage), if that makes a difference?

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 - lots of the previous answers are for older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it actually an error, or just a warning? I don't think it's complaining about `libnextcloud_csync.so -> libnextcloud_csync.so.0`, but because `libnextcloud_csync.so.0` isn't a further symlink to something like `libnextcloud_csync.so.0.3`.

Comment: @steeldriver I think it is an error because when I `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` nothing is returned.

Comment: AFAIK that's expected - `ld.so.conf` is the "system" way of locating libraries, whereas `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a *separate* kludge for making user- or application-specific library specifications